# How to capture unknown number of words in between a negative lookbehind catch term regex?

Tags: python, regex, data-mining

I am trying to exclude records which have the word "owner" somewhere preceding the word "dog"

- the owner has a dog (exclude)
- the owner has a black and brown dog (exclude)
- John has a dog (include)
- John has a black and brown dog (include)

Here is current regex:

```
\b(?<!owner\s)\w+\sdog\b
```

This works for a single unknown word ('owner **has** dog' is excluded but 'owner **has a** dog' is included)), however, I am unable to capture multiple words which retain its negative look behind across all words between "owner" and "dog".

Many Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following regular expression to verify that the string contains the word "dog" that is not preceded by the word "owner".

```
^(?:(?!\bowner\b).)*\bdog\b
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/S8OJgx/1/) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [Python code](https://tio.run/##jY@xDsIwDER3f8XRhQRVLGxIqCviFwhICYSmAuLKKar4@pIWiQExMNrv7uxrn13guBqG5t6ydBBPZEWwwZ6AYschItgEizPXRfm1czd7usLGM5xwH0cN@sDJI09e0CRsHzW/fRz9JLCRu5DhJzBPE3h7vq6N8C/w45eCDkRjF5kfVbVW1cy4yWKcXuqFcVlj3JzowoKEJiJXX@fwVprYqVTCMd@U@GXyVk5BSYmkNTQNwws)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                : anchor match to beginning of string
(?:              : begin a non-capture group
  (?!\bowner\b)  : use a negative lookahead to assert that the current
                   position in the string is not followed by "owner"
  .              : match a character
)                : end non-capture group
*                : execute non-capture group 0+ times
\bdog\b          : match 'dog' surrounded by word boundaries
```

The technique of matching a sequence of individual characters that do not begin an outlawed word is called [Tempered Greedy Token Solution](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

Comment: Very interesting.  Thank you.  A negative lookbehind also seems to work.  But what I don't understand is why a positive lookbehind doesn't match the opposite set - where `owner` does  precede `dog`? (Sorry for asking this question in a comment, if you prefer, I can fork the "fork" the original question.)

Comment: Cannot thank you enough, you have been a massive help

Comment: @Mark, if "owner" must precede "dog" a positive lookbehind would look like `(?<=\bowner\b.*)`. That's a *variable-length* positive lookbehind, which is not supported by Python's standard `re` module. It is supported, however, by Python's PyPI regex module. Simpler, however, is just to write `\bowner\b.*\bdog\b`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to start matching any char except `o` or a newline.

Then in case you encounter an o, assert that it is not the word *owner* followed by matching any char except an o or a newline and optionally repeat that process until you match the word dog.

```
 ^[^o\r\n]*(?:(?!\bowner\b)o[^o\r\n]*)*\bdog\b
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `[^o\r\n]*` Match 0+ times any char except o or a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!\bowner\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not the word owner directly to the right
  - `o[^o\r\n]*` Match o followed by 0+ times any char except o or newline
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\bdog\b` Match the word dog

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pa7IA6/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/M5Eka6)

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply. I was wondering whether it would be possible to have this given within a sentence that contains the word "dog" that is extracted from an entire paragraph? e.g. "Hello my name is Sean. John has a dog." where the regex is only applied between the . after "Sean" and then at the end of the sentence "dog."

Comment: @SeanFarrell You could use a positive lookbehind asserting either the start of the string or a dot and exclude the dot from matching. `(?:(?<=\.)|(?<=^))[^o\r\n.]*(?:(?!\bowner\b)o[^o\r\n.]*)*\bdog\b`https://regex101.com/r/E5pKl2/1